# CASE Statement To Reflect On The Last Day Of A Quarter

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a field, lets call it purchase_date that reflects on when an item was purchased. There is also a field called tutorial_date which reflects on when the user who purchased the item was given a tutorial.

In my query, I want it to reflect on if the tutorial occurred within the same quarter as the purchase. If I wanted to just focus on specific quarter it would look something like:

```
CASE WHEN (tutorial_date >= '2016-07-01' AND tutorial_date <= '2016-09-30') THEN successful
```

But that makes things very tedious. What I want to do is hard code it so I can get that same result, regardless of when it was purchased. So say it was purchased in September of 2016, it would automatically have those parameters. If it was purchased in February of 2015 it would fall into whatever quarter that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for BigQuery Legacy SQL

```
SELECT 
  *, 
  YEAR(purchase_date) = YEAR(tutorial_date) AND 
  QUARTER(purchase_date) = QUARTER(tutorial_date) AS successful
FROM
  (SELECT '2016-05-02' AS purchase_date, '2016-07-02' AS tutorial_date),
  (SELECT '2016-06-02' AS purchase_date, '2016-07-02' AS tutorial_date),
  (SELECT '2016-07-02' AS purchase_date, '2016-09-02' AS tutorial_date),
  (SELECT '2016-08-02' AS purchase_date, '2016-10-02' AS tutorial_date)
```